# wsl2-GUI-emacs open file with explorer.exe instead of xdg-open

Tags: emacs, wsl-2

I am working on wsl2+emacs GUI version with VcxSrv window manager server.

Within the GUI version, emacs does not open files with windows-app as it does in wsl2-terminal-emacs.

Take an example:

on dired window, I strike key `&` invoking `dired-do-async-shell-command` to open file "demestic.01.pdf";

it prompt to run with "xdg-open" rather than "explorer.exe".

Is it possible to replace "xdg-open" with "explorer.exe"?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**:
You can take a look at `wslview` which is a part of [wslu](https://github.com/wslutilities/wslu#installation) (it ships with latest versions of Ubuntu distro) and is a better alternative. `wslview` will try to detect the protocol used(`file:`, `http:`, `https:`), check whether it is a Linux path or Windows path, translate it to the proper form and open the file/folder/link.

And if you want everything to be opened in Windows, just create a link:

```
sudo ln -s ../../bin/wslview /usr/local/bin/xdg-open
```

So, whenever `xdg-open` is invoked, everything would open up in Windows

Comment: ty, but it's for wsl1.

Comment: wslu does support WSL2, isn't it ? you can similarly create a symbolic link to xdg-open-wsl script

Comment: Amazing, I am beyond exciting to say thank you! the problem turns out to be a pain for eveyone lol and solved.

Comment: Welcome :) Glad that it helped and thanks for selecting it as the answer